# Can we use meta programming in groovy to block some string variable from getting print

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree, groovyshell

```
def sen = "sensitiveValue"
def nonSen = "nonSensitiveValue"
println sen
println nonSen
```

expected output

```
*****
nonSensitiveValue
```

String.metaClass program to  avoid printing ?

Comment: Poor man's solution: `metaClass.println = { String value -> System.out.println(value.replaceAll('sensitiveValue', '*****')) }`